# How to get 2 different specified legends in ggplot maps, R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making a map that needs to 2 legends. 1 legend shows the temperature, and another legend shows if points are labelled as zone 1:4. When I try to add the second color scale, for the second legend I get the error

```
Scale for 'fill' is already present. Adding another scale for
'fill', which will replace the existing scale.
Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale
```

When I don't specify the second color scale I get the map I want however, the points are not the colour I want them to be. I tried using `new_scale_color()` in the code but that doesn't work either, it's the same error.
 Here is some sample data

```
#Dataframe for Ocean Temperature
mapoc_temp = expand.grid(data.frame(Longitude= seq(-64.5,-62.4,0.1), 
                                    Latitude= seq(42.7,44.8,0.1),
                                    year = sample(c(2016,2017,2018), 22, replace = T),
                                    month = sample(month.abb, 22, replace = T)))
mapoc_temp$Ave = runif(nrow(mapoc_temp))

#Dataframe for the points
individual_dets = data.frame(longitude= seq(-64.5,-62.4,0.1),
                             latitude= seq(42.7,44.8,0.1),
                             year = sample(c(2016, 2017, 2018), 22, replace = T),
                             Zone = sample(c(1:4), 22, replace = T),
                             month = sample(month.abb, 22, replace = T))
```

This is the code I use to map it, you will need this entire code to see my error.

```
library(mapdata)

#Import Canada map
canada = map_data("worldHires", "Canada")


## Map of temperature across Scotian Shelf
ggplot(mapoc_temp, aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude)) + 
  #plotting the temperature as color
  geom_raster(aes(fill = Ave, 
                  x = Longitude), interpolate = TRUE) +
  #getting the map of Scotian shelf
  geom_polygon(data = canada, 
               aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), 
               colour="grey50", fill = 'grey55')+
  #Coordinates I'm interested in looking at
  coord_sf(xlim=c(-64.5,-62.8), ylim=c(42.7,45)) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(name = "Temp.\n(°C)", option = "C") +

#Use this to get second legend?
  new_scale_color() +

  #to try and get zones overtop  
  geom_point(data = individual_dets,
             aes(x = longitude,
                 y = latitude,
                 color = as.numeric(Zone),
                 fill = as.numeric(Zone)),
             pch = 21, size = 2) +

  #fill the zones with second legend.... Does not work
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#01579B", "#4FC3F7", "#ffa600", "#ff6361")) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#01579B", "#4FC3F7", "#ffa600", "#ff6361"))
```

If I don't use the last chunk of code

```
 #fill the zones with second legend.... Does not work
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#01579B", "#4FC3F7", "#ffa600", "#ff6361")) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#01579B", "#4FC3F7", "#ffa600", "#ff6361"))
```

I get this picture
[image]

But I need the points to be those exact colors I have in the chunk of code. Does anyone know how to add the second legend scale to the ggplot map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use a `pch = 21`, `ggplot` will use a point with color being the same fill (I guess it is pch = 16 by default), so, you don't need twice `scale_fill` but instead can manipulate points using `scale_color_manual`.

Also, you are converting `Zone` in a numeric format so `ggplot2` is plotting it as a continuous scale. So, you can't pass only 4 color values on it. Either, you have to plot `Zone` as a factor and use `scale_color_manual` to set the color for each zone (which makes sense) or you can plot `Zone` as a gradient as you are doing but you need to use `scale_color_gradient` then to set the color scheme.

```r
library(mapdata)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mapoc_temp, aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude)) + 
  geom_raster(aes(fill = Ave, 
                  x = Longitude), interpolate = TRUE) +
  geom_polygon(data = canada, 
               aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), 
               colour="grey50", fill = 'grey55')+
  coord_sf(xlim=c(-64.5,-62.8), ylim=c(42.7,45)) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(name = "Temp.\n(°C)", option = "C") +
  geom_point(data = individual_dets,
             aes(x = longitude,
                 y = latitude,
                 color = as.factor(Zone)),
                 #fill = as.numeric(Zone)),
             size = 2) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#01579B", "#4FC3F7", "#ffa600", "#ff6361"), name = "Zone")
```

[image]

Does it look what you are trying to achieve ?